# Prevent immediate fire of Quartz.Net Event

Tags: c#, quartz.net

When I create a simple trigger and assign it to a scheduler, it fires immediately and then again at the scheduled interval. How can it be made to only fire at the specified time?

Example code below:

```
// construct a scheduler factory
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();            

// construct job info
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", "Default", typeof(DumbJob));

// Example trigger to fire after 1 minute, no repeat
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeMinutelyTrigger(1, 0);

// Schedule the job
trigger.Name = "demoTrigger";
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);                       

sched.Start();  

public class DumbJob : IJob
{
   public DumbJob()
   {
   }

    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dumb job is running");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger object has a StartTimeUtc property which you can use to specify when the trigger will start firing and so on. Here is an example:

```
     trigger.StartTimeUtc = TriggerUtils.GetEvenMinuteDate(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
```

this creates a trigger that will start firing the next even minute.

Comment: Thanks ryudice, worked like a charm...note I had to make it DateTime.NowUTC as it's all UTC time.

Comment: Anybody know how to do this with Quartz.NET 2.0+ ? - StartTimeUtc has no setter in the latest version.

Comment: DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, item.reoccurring, DateTime.UtcNow) works better for me. TriggerUtils.GetEvenMinuteDate will Round Up/Down the Minutes.

Comment: @SpaceBison it is called .StartAt() and you will use it before calling .Build() on the trigger